# Location of shell script file, which is to be executed by local git hook

Tags: git, shell, githooks

I'm using [git hooks](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) for the first time and stuck on an issue that seems simple but I haven't found any answer so far.

I have created a shell script (it works fine when called directly) which I want to call inside the git **post-commit**-hook. I know I could include the script itself in the hook, but that could get chaotic if more scripts are added.

The contents of the hook-file looks like this:

```
!/bin/sh

sh myshellscript.sh # This doesn't work by the way

: Nothing
```

The hook is definitely executed but **myshellscript.sh** is not found.

Where is the best place to put **myshellscript.sh** and how do I reference it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook will be executed with the current directory set to `$GIT_DIR` which is usually the root directory of the repository.

If your script, `myshellscript.sh`, is in the hooks directory you would need to run

```
sh .git/hooks/myshellscript.sh
```